# Link a Case to a Contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, civicase

Is there a way or does anyone have a current extension that allows us to link a specific Contribution to a specific Case? We'd like to be able to report on the contribution amounts we have received for a specific incoming grant case.

I know of this older extension, but it seems to be outdated (not compatible since Civi version 4.x, from what it seems): https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.casecontribution.

Does anyone else have a more up-to-date extension or any other way to link those two entities so we can report on them?

Comment: ah, right I see https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.casecontribution/issues/1 so i won't make misleading comment about how extensions often outlast their 'version'. would crossing jaap's palm with some silver be an option

Answer (score 2):

I have a [forked version](https://github.com/pradpnayak/org.civicoop.casecontribution) which should work on the latest Civi version.

Comment: Very nice, Pradeep. It looks like yours has a report addition as well, I like that. After reviewing the original code, however, I'm realizing the extension doesn't do certain things like having the cases list show up as a select field on the new or edit contribution form. It also doesn't seem to work with the CompuCorp CiviCase extension, something we use a lot. The case's contributions don't show up in a tab there. Those are both items we need, so I'm looking at forking/rebuilding it as well. Maybe we can combine things later on (though my code is likely not production ready).

Comment: Hi Pradeep and Paul B, would it not be worth doing a PR to the original extension so that one is up to date as well?

Comment: I have already submitted PR(https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.casecontribution/pull/2) around 2 years ago